# Using a stylesheet to create a footer that prints the directory name of the current file

Tags: stylesheet

I am trying to use a stylesheet to create a footer that will use the directory name of the current file.  For example, consider the following temp.nb file with stored within the CalculusI directory.  That is,

CalculusI/temp.nb

I would like the footer to simply print out CalculusI.  I have tried the following to no avail.  Any ideas?

```
 Cell[StyleData["Notebook"],
 PageFooters->{{None, 
    FileNameSplit[NotebookDirectory[]][[-1]], None}, {None, 
    None, None}},
 PrintingOptions->{"FacingPages"->True,
 "FirstPageFace"->Right,
 "FirstPageFooter"->True,
 "FirstPageHeader"->False}]
```

I can succesfully get the filename as the footer by using the following in the stylesheet replacing FileNameSplit[NotebookDirectory[]][[-1]] in my code above with the following.

```
CurrentValue["NotebookFileName"]
```

However, I can't figure out how to grab the directory name (CalculusI) for the file and use it as the footer.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you must use boxes in the [`PageFooters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PageFooters) option setting. A typical boxes expression consists of *Box objects with lists and strings. For example:

```
ToBoxes[f[x, "y"]]
```

> RowBox[{"f", "[", RowBox[{"x", ",", "\"y\""}], "]"}]

[`CurrentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentValue) is special, because it gets evaluated by the FrontEnd, and it evaluates to a string. This is why you can use [`CurrentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentValue) in the option setting. However, adding [`FileNameSplit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileNameSplit) means the FrontEnd can't evaluate it, so it is an expression and doesn't get rendered properly.

So, use a [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell) object instead. For example, the following returns the desired directory:

```
Dynamic @ FileNameTake @ CurrentValue["NotebookDirectory"]
```

The corresponding [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell) expression is:

```
Cell @ BoxData @ ToBoxes @ Dynamic @ FileNameTake @ CurrentValue["NotebookDirectory"]
```

> Cell[BoxData[
>     DynamicBox[
>      ToBoxes[FileNameTake[CurrentValue["NotebookDirectory"]], StandardForm]]]]

The following style should do what you want:

```
Cell[StyleData["Notebook"],
    PageFooters->{
        {
        None,
        Cell[
            BoxData @ DynamicBox @ ToBoxes @ FileNameTake @ CurrentValue["NotebookDirectory"],
            ShowStringCharacters->False
        ],
        None
        },
        {None, None, None}
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it!! I overcompplicated this initially in my answer, but just change "-1" to "-2" as in:

```
NotebookFileName[]
```

Gives you:

```
C:\Users\Cody\Desktop\directorymain\subdirectory\targetnb.nb
```

And so:

```
FileNameSplit[NotebookFileName[]][[-2]]
```

Gives you:

```
subdirectory
```

As output! Relevant references:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NamingAndFindingFiles.html
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileNameTake.html

Hope this helps!! Also of value:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConstructAFilePathProgrammatically.html

The workflow pages are some of my more favorite ones to review for strategies.

Comment: I’m sorry.  I should have been more clear.  My problem isn’t how to get the name of the directory.  Instead it is how to maybe it appear as a footer using a Stylesheet.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain you would just replace what you reference in your question, I am on mobile currently and can test it in a bit, but: "I can succesfully get the filename as the footer by using the following in the stylesheet replacing FileNameSplit[NotebookDirectory[]][[-1]] in my code above with the following." So it should work if you replace that with FileNameSplit[NotebookFileName[]][[-2]] --If my understanding is correct. I can edit my answer when I get to a PC

Comment: Hello.  I tried putting this direclty into the stylesheet.  For some reason it doesn't like the call.  It does work with CurrentValue["NotebookFileName"], but I don't want the file name.  I can't seem to find a similair way using CurrentValue to get the directory name.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain and, to be clear, it would print just "temp.nb"? Or "Calculusl/temp.nb"?

Comment: Yes... using CurrentValue["NotebookFileName"], I get temp.nb as the footer when I print to PDF.

Comment: making progress with a slightly different call.... CurrentValue["NotebookFullFileName"]... but now can't split the file name to grab the part I want.  : /